# Как в MySQL Connector / Python использовать IN

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Всем привет! Подскажите как правильно использовать оператор IN

Есть такой запрос "UPDATE `order` SET Cut_Mission_Id = %s WHERE Id IN (%s)"

Делал так

```
query = "UPDATE `order` SET Cut_Mission_Id = %s WHERE Id IN %s"
args = (5, (5, 6))
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

И так

```
query = "UPDATE `order` SET Cut_Mission_Id = %s WHERE Id IN (%s)"
args = (5, "5, 6")
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

В первом случае запрос не работает, во втором случае передается только одна цифра и находится только одна строка(должно быть 2).
Не нашел как это делается! Помогите!

Comment: Боюсь это проблема. либо в текст подставлять сразу значения, либо писать IN(%s,%s,%s,...) и соответственно передавать отдельными элементами массива

Comment: Ну это очень странно! Это не самый редкий оператор )

Comment: По крайней мере так работают драйвера БД во всех языках. Происходит привязка _значения_, и одно значение в виде текста - это совершенно не тот список из нескольких значений, который пишется в тексте в IN. было бы логично, если бы можно было передать массив. Но я ни разу не слышал про драйвера БД позволяющие передавать массивы значений, как один параметр

Comment: Лично я предпочитаю в таких случаях генерить и вставлять в текст вопросительные знаки по количеству элементов в моем массиве для передачи (в питоне, конечно вместо вопросов используются %s)